# Line Intersect Plane Z=0

Tags: geometry

If got a problem with getting the point of intersect a line throug a plane. I cant find any information about it. I can find information about a plane that is not flat.

I have a graphical representation of my problem: http://faceting.vondsten.nl/hmm.cgi (the balls should be coming on the plane but they dont. so i used 1/2 of the line to see if my line particle was working)

This is my situation i have a plane with 4 points: (-1, 1, 0) (1, 1, 0) (1, -1, 0) (-1, -1, 0) (x,y,z)

I got line drawed by the 2 points:

P1 = (0.5, 5.55111512312578e-017, 0.207106781186547)

P2 = (0.5, 0.707106781186547, -0.5)

I get this far that i can make a partical. (x, y, z)+t[x-x1, x-y1, z-z1] but when i try to use the equation x + y + z = 0 the awnser wont get 0 for the Z.

I dont know what ore where i need to look to get my calculation right. I have a feeling that x + y + z = 0 isnt going to work.

How can i calculate the intersection by a plane that is using 4 points? The x and y can also be changed, they are infinity.

Sorry for my typos, im dutch and i did not have any higher math on school. So maybey my thinking is completely wrong.

Manny thanks,

Christian

Calculation:

x = 0.5

y = 5.55111512312578e-017

z = 0.207106781186547

a = 0.5

b = 0.707106781186547

c = -0.5

---

Making Partical

xt = (x - a)

yt = (y - b)

zt = (z - c)

---

Calculation with plane (x + y + z = 0):

i = (xt + yt + zt)

l = (x + y + z)

o = (i + l)

---

x = (x + (xt * o)) = Awnser: 0.5

y = (y + (yt * o)) = Awnser: 0.207106781186548

z = (z + (zt * o)) = Awnser: -7.21644966006352e-016 is NOT nul

---

I know for shure that this part is wrong:

i = (xt + yt + zt)

l = (x + y + z)

o = (i + l)

Comment: Why do you set $x+y+z=0$ when $z=0$ is what you want? If you set $z=0$ instead of $x+y+z=0$, you should indeed get $z=0$.

Comment: the problem is that i dont know how to put this in a formula to get it to z=0 so i used x + y + z + xt + yt + zt. The results what im getting are all different, im a bit confiused how i need to calculate this.

Comment: If you know how to plug your formulas for $x$, $y$, and $z$ into $x+y+z=0$, how can you possibly be unable to _do the very same thing_ for $z=0$? It's **literally the same thing as you have already done once**, or rather one-third of what you have already done, since there is no $x$ or $y$ you need to plug anything in for.

Comment: if i do that then my awnser is: 0.5, 0.560660171779821, -0.353553390593274 and isnt 0 i just dont understand how to get the formula right. Im so confiused. Im already trying this for a week,

Comment: I have no idea what that notation means.

Comment: I just dont know the formula for my problem.

Comment: x @Christian: What are you actually doing? You're just posting results without any explanation of what it is you're doing to get those results. Are you still setting $x+y+z=0$ instead of setting $z=0$? Which $t$ do you get when you solve? _How_ do you compute that $t$, in detail?

Comment: x = 0.5
y = 5.55111512312578e-017
z = 0.207106781186547

a = 0.5
b = 0.707106781186547
c = -0.5

xt = (x - a)
yt = (y - b)
zt = (z - c)

i = (xt + yt + zt)
l = (x + y + z)

o = (i + l)

x = (x + (xt * o))
y = (y + (yt * o))
z = (z + (zt * o)) This is what im doing, and probebly totaly wrong.

Comment: Again, you need to **explain what you're doing** ("explain" means in English, with words) and not just spew a sea of formulas and symbols without any explanation of what you're doing with them.

Comment: Hang on, ill work it out

Comment: How do i need to explain what i am doing, I have put the calculation at the top. How do you want that i explain? Do i need to set all calculations with it? ore?!

Comment: I have put it all in the top thread i hope this is easyer reading and put the explanation with it.

Comment: You have just dumped another load of formulas into your question without any explanation of what your purpose in writing each of them is, or what the connection between them is. You need to USE WORDS to explain what the purpose of each of your formulas is. ***Refusing to write any English words does not make what you're doing "more mathematical"; it just makes it impossible to understand what you think you're doing and why you're doing it -- no matter whether you're trying to communicate with a mathematician or a layperson***.

Comment: (In the mean time some telegraphic headlines have been added. WRITE COMPLETE SENTENCES IF YOU WANT TO BE UNDERSTOOD, dammit! And why are you still setting $x+y+z=0$ for the plane if what you want is actually $z=0$? Why do you insist on adding $x$ and $y$ to the poor defenseless $z$?

Comment: And $-7\times 10^{-16}$ is pretty darn close to $0$, even though the strange unexplained procedure you used to come up with it seems off.

Answer (score 0):

With less ridiculous precision, your two points are $P_1(0.5, 0, 0.2)$ and $P_2(0.5, 0.7, -0.5)$. The difference between these coordinates is $(0, 0.7, -0.7)$, so a parametric equation for your line would be
$$ t \mapsto (0.5,\; 0,\; 0.2) + t(0,\; 0.7,\; -0.7) $$
or in other words
$$ t \mapsto (0.5+0t,\; 0+0.7t,\; 0.2-0.7t)$$

You have already figured out that the plane you want to intersect with is given by $z=0$, and since $z=0.2-0.7t$, we need to solve
$$ 0.2-0.7t = 0 $$
which easily gives $t=\frac27$. We then plug this $t$ into the parametric equation to get
$$ (0.5,\; 0.7\cdot\frac27,\; 0.2-0.7\cdot\frac27 ) = (0.5, 0.2, 0)$$
for the point of intersection.

You can repeat this calculation with your boatloads-of-significant-digits if you want.

Comment: Thanks, im going to try if i can figure it all out, im sorry i can not explain my calculation as what you did, I have never got this at school.

Comment: One question what is the formula to get (0.5,\; 0.7\cdot\frac27,\; 0.2-0.7\cdot\frac27 ) = (0.5, 0.2, 0), why can 0.5 be 0.5 without a formule? and why is 0.2 in the z and not in the x and the y?

Comment: @Christian: That's simply inserting $t=\frac27$ into the parametric equation two formulas earlier.

Comment: Im almost getting it but not the y how can y becomes 0.7 * (2/7) i do understand that x = (0,5 - 0 * (0/0) = 0.5 and z= (0.2 - 0.7 * (2/7) but if i use the formule for the y = (0 - 0.7 * (0/7)??? i get 0 why is this 0.7 * (2/7) or is the x also x = 0.5 - 0 * (2/7)???

Comment: think i got it (i think) x: 0.5 +   (0   * (2/7)) = 0.5
y:   0 +   (0,7 * (2/7)) = 0.2
z: 0,2 +   (-0,7 * (2/7)) = 0

Comment: @Christian: By the original formula $y$ is $0+0.7t$. When you set $t=\frac27$ in this, you get $0+0.7\cdot\frac27$, but adding $0$ does nothing, so this is the same as $0.7\cdot\frac27$. Why would you have $\frac07$ anywhere?

Comment: Becouse i need to use it in my software and there is no way to change the static formule to a dynamic formule. The input can be dynamic not the calculation.

Comment: Still one more question: can i just make the negative 0.2 −0.7t=0 positive without any problems?! 0.2−0.7t=0 becomes 0.2 : 0.7t=0 -> 2/7? And one more problem, if i use straigth lines, it seems that the calculation cant handle that. It is putting the points above the z=0.

Comment: Again one more question, why does the awnser not get at zero when using 64 bit calculation?!

Comment: @Christian: There will always be rounding errors. I'm not sure what you mean by the previous comment.

Comment: Still having one problem! What if the zise is not 1 but 2??? I get strange results. What will t be then? Thanks

Comment: @Christian: I have no idea what a "zise" is.

Comment: Already got it :) fractions... i forgot to use fractions at higher values to make +t. Problem solved! (zise = size) sorry!

Comment: I was trying some things out and i wonder how the sum will be when is for example Z=-0.4 would you explain that what the sum wil be that im going to understand the physics behind it?!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Henning Makholm!

It worked! The calculation can handle all points but lines that have a 90 degree angle on the plane will not get on the plane. But you can zero the z axis then. Also the rounding in 64bit shoult be done at 14 decimals to get zero.

Again manny thanks to Henning!

Christian